# Show that a linear transformation is surjective if and only if it sends generating sets into generating sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm struglying to answer this question, I think the questions is kind ambiguos since it doesn't give from where to where is $T$

Can someone explain me?

Comment: Assume that $T$ is from an arbitrary vector space $V$ to another vector space $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Let V and W be vector spaces and $T:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map

Assume $T$ sends generator set $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$  to another generator set $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ and $n \geq m$ so we can say $T(v_i)=w_i$

Let $w\in W$ then there exists real numbers $c_i$ such that

$w=c_1w_1+...+c_mw_m=c_1T(v_1)+...+c_mT(v_m)=T(c_1v_1)+...+T(c_mv_m)=T(c_1v_1+...+c_mv_m)$

that means for all $w\in W$ there exists and $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=w$ so T is
surjective

Assume T is surjective then for all $w \in W$ there can be found a $v\in V$ such that

$T(v)=w$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n)=c_1T(v_1)+...+c_nT(v_n)=w$

which means $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ generates all $w \in W$ so T sends a generator set to another generator set